# How to handle notification after user clicks with PushPlugin Ionic?

Tags: cordova, notifications, ionic-framework

I have everything working, but having trouble handling after user clicks the notification. Instead of going to index, ideally I want them to go to another route.

Comment: This question is too broad.  What have you tried?  Please post your work-in-progress implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link resolving this:

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/issues/213

When the app is in the background and receive the notification you can save the playload to the *localStorage*:

```
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived', function(event, notification) {
   if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid() && notification.event == 'message') {
        var newsid=notification.payload.newsid;
        if (typeof newsid != 'undefined') {
            // save the newsid to read it later in the resume event
            $window.localStorage.setItem('goafterpush',newsid);
        }
    }
});
```

And then in the *resume* event you can read the previous saved playload and use that data to change the state of the app and redirect to another route:

```
$ionicPlatform.on("resume",function(event){
     // read the newsid saved previously when received the notification
     var goafterpush=$window.localStorage.getItem('goafterpush');
     if (goafterpush) {
         $window.localStorage.removeItem('goafterpush');
         $state.go('app.newsdetail',{id:goafterpush});
     }
});
```

Comment: I have edited the answer to add some code and explication